# looking for an appropriate word for something that has problem

Tags: single-word-requests

I need to know an appropriate single word that could be used for something that has some problems (devices) or errors (for programs)! to describe something that has got a bit flaw which could be fixed.

some thing I could with the 'Not Working' part as in the following example:

```
I need a list of all [Not Working] devices in the stock.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may say *[faulty or defective](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/faulty)*:

> - Containing a fault or defect; imperfect .

Fault:

> - (Electronics) A defect in a circuit or wiring caused by imperfect connections, poor insulation, grounding, or shorting.

Source: The American Heritage® Dictionary